# LoadRunner web_reg_save_param, ord=all, paramName_count issues

Tags: parsing, integer, loadrunner

I am using LoadRunner version 12.02 - Build 2739

Looking at an old, yet correct 'guide' shows that I have used the statements correctly (3rd Point, around 1/3rd of the way down the page, inside the code block - [the `atoi` statement](http://motevich.blogspot.co.il/2007/11/loadrunner-correlation-dynamic-data.html)).

But I am still unable to convert the _count parameter to an int-Variable.

In the script, before the call is made;

```
web_reg_save_param(
"ParamName=rotaPeople",
"LB=someText",
"RB=\")",
"Ord=ALL",
LAST);
```

After the web call the save_param function is placed before, the output log shows;

```
Notify: Saving Parameter "ParamName=rotaPeople_count = 21".
```

Inside the script, after the call is made, and the count has been totaled;

```
lr_output_message("RP_C:%d",lr_eval_string("{rotaPeople_count}"));
lr_output_message("RP_C:%s",lr_eval_string("{rotaPeople_count}"));
peoplesCount = atoi(lr_eval_string("{rotaPeople_count}"));
lr_output_message("PC:%d",peoplesCount);
```

In the logs after the above executions are made;

```
Warning: The string 'rotaPeople_count' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
RP_C:110826864
Warning: The string 'rotaPeople_count' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
RP_C:{rotaPeople_count}
Warning: The string 'rotaPeople_count' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
PC:0
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Note: The Warning messages are expected

Note: Workaround: Used `web_reg_save_param_regex()` and created a regular expression. Using the returned _count parameter within a for-loop worked. Keeping question open, as the original problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a soon to be deprecated API `web_reg_save_param` which does not support the `ParamName` syntax. In this API the second parameter is always the parameter name and therefore the correct use would be:

```
web_reg_save_param(
"rotaPeople",
"LB=someText",
"RB=\")",
"Ord=ALL",
LAST);
```

The proper API to use is `web_reg_save_param_ex` which does support the syntax you used so the call should look like:

```
web_reg_save_param_ex(
"ParamName=rotaPeople",
"LB=someText",
"RB=\")",
"Ord=ALL",
LAST);
```

Then the rest of your code should work properly.

I am not sure what you are doing but you might want to take a look at the somewhat unknown API `lr_paramarr_random` which will automatically pull a random value from the parameters array.

Comment: Thanks for this Buzzy, you've helped me to no end - I'd have been scratching my head for a lot longer!


It's a shame that the documentation didn't update along with the version changes to highlight it's incompatibility.

I knew of the `lr_paramarr_random` function, but I need to use all of the capture elements for a subsequest submit, so it wouldn't have worked. - Good suggestion though :)


Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help. I will notify the documentation team about this issue.

Comment: Thanks - just to note, the documentation does state it is deprecated, but it does still exist and can, as explained above, capture the elements specified, even with the `"ParamName=..."`.
You said it rightly though: it is soon to be deprecated, so maybe the documentation should state _"soon to be deprecated: remaining functionality has changed to (your answer)."_ Otherwise, it might be best to not cause unnecessary work for the documentation team. You've been a tremendous help - It's just a shame I haven't enough rep to upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
   web_reg_save_param(
  "rotaPeople",
 "LB=someText",
 "RB=\")",
 "Ord=ALL",
  LAST);

  lr_output_message("PC:%d",atoi(lr_eval_string("{rotaPeople_count}")));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the previous answer had already highlighted the issue with an explanation as to why the issue was occurring, along with the suggested function going forward - I suggest you take a read, as promoting `web_reg_save_param` is probably not a good idea any more... Thanks for your input however

Comment: As someone with 20++ years of LoadRunner, I have no problem in using web_reg_save_param().  Yes, it has been deprecated, but only recently.  Heck, functions which were deprecated as far back as version 6 still work, but you would have issues getting support if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ord=all,see the run time data which value you want to capture,If you want to capture the 10th value please use ord=10,automatically this warning will remove from output log.

Answer (score 0):

Example for capturing an array of dynamic values:

```
Action()
{

int i;
int ncount;
char ParamName[100];

web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS");



    web_reg_save_param("trackingno","LB=;","RB= (NTN 0430)","search=All","ord=all",LAST);

    web_submit_data("barcode.pl", 
        "Action=http://qtetools.rmtc.fedex.com/barcode/cgi-bin/barcode.pl", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=http://qtetools.rmtc.fedex.com/barcode/html/barcode.shtml", 
        "Snapshot=t2.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=formcode", "Value=0430", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=count", "Value=10", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=narrow", "Value=2", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);


    ncount= atoi(lr_eval_string("{trackingno_count}"));

    for (i =1;i <= ncount;i++)
       {
    sprintf(ParamName, "{trackingno_%d}", i);

       lr_output_message("Value of %s: %s",ParamName,lr_eval_string(ParamName));
           }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you work for FEDEX you should not be testing their website.  In fact, the LoadRunner license states that you should not be using this tool against sites you do not own, manage, control or have permission from those who do.